# How to get the values of a form within a Handlebars-Partial?

Tags: express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am new working with Handlebars and Partials. Actually I have a form within a partial (see Screenshot).
[Basic Form within Partial basicInfol.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImYqV.png)

Its code is a simple html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/registrationSteps.css' />

<body>
<form id='form' class='form' method='POST'>
  <div style='display: flex; flex-direction: column; max-width: 100%; padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px'>
    <label for='firstname'>First name *</label>
    <input class='input' type='text' tabindex='1' id='firstname' name='firstname' value='{{firstname}}'
           required autofocus aria-required='true' />
    <label for='lastname'>Last name *</label>
    <input class='input' type='text' tabindex='2' id='lastname' name='lastname' value='{{lastname}}'
           required aria-required='true' />
    .....
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Within the registrationSteps.html I have the following section where the partial gets loaded:

```
 <section id='step-1' class='form-step'>
      <h2 class='font-normal'>Basic information</h2>
      {{> basicInfo}}
      <div class='mt-3'>
        <button class='button btn-navigate-form-step' type='button' step_number='2'>Next</button>
      </div>
    </section>
```

When the Next-Button is clicked I want to save the content of the partials-form so that I can save it later into a database. But how can I get the value of the forms within my parent html form?

I would be very happy if somebody coult help me!

Kind regards
Verena

Comment: You would need to share some code in order for others to help you.